# Animation Nodes sockets stopped connecting

Tags: animation-nodes

I was playing with creating objects on a spline (following the Dominoes.blend example file) Something I did crashed blender. I reopened the file and I can no longer connect the purple spline socket to a purple spline socket. ???
I tried closing blender and starting from a new file. I opened the dominoes file and added new nodes (spline from object, get spline length) and was unable to connect the purple sockets.
[image: sockets!]

What does it mean when a socket is faded (transparent)?

Thanks

Comment: Transparent mean it expects a list of splines, semi transparent means it expect both lists and single elements (The socket is vectroized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Splines from Object* outputs a list of splines by default because a curve object can have **multiple splines** in Blender. You can see that it outputs a list by looking at the socket transparency.

You have two options:

- Use a **Get List Element** node to get the first element from the list.
- Open the **advanced settings** of the Splines from Object node and switch the *Import Type* to **Single**.